# How to validate input string using while loop

Tags: java, validation, shortcut

I know this might seem like a simple/silly question, but I am trying to keep my code as organized and simple as possible.  The problem that I am having is with a while loop for validation.  I am validating a string input.  I am using the validation simply to make sure that something is entered.  The only time I would like the while loop to run is when no information is entered at all, so I would like to include every character and symbol.  The question that I have, is that I am wondering if there is a shorter way to include every character possible except for simply hitting enter of course.  Here is the simple code snippet.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("contactRequest.txt");


System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
String email = input.nextLine();
while(!email.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
{
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a valid E-Mail.");
        email = input.nextLine();
}
out.println("E-Mail: " + email);
```

Comment: Are you testing if there's an input or not? If so, use `hasNextLine()`

Comment: The last line is out.println because it will print that text into the txt file that is specified with the print writer.  All of this is an assignment for class so I do not have to call from the document, just have to store the information.  And ultimately yes, I just need to make sure that there is some form of input besides hitting enter.

Comment: you're right, sorry about that

Comment: Why the semicolon at the end of the while loop?

Comment: What I am more looking for is, I can place all the characters that I can think of in the brackets where a-zA-Z is, but I would prefer not to place every key stroke possible (more or less) so where a-z factors in all letters a through z, is there a way to do that with characters?

Comment: semicolon was a typo, it is not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about restructuring it as a do-while and only having one print/scan?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("contactRequest.txt");

String email;
String prompt = "Please enter your name: ";
do {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    email = input.nextLine();
    prompt = "\nPlease enter a valid E-Mail.\n"
} while (!email.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));

out.println("E-Mail: " + email);
```

Comment: This looks a little more structured, but it does not really answer my question.  My code works properly I just need the validation requirement (a-zA-Z) to factor in characters.  I can make it work, but the only way that I can figure out how to do it is to manually enter every possible character  Is there a shortcut like a-z factors letters a through z with special characters?.

Comment: Thank you!  I looked for that exact information, but somehow I couldn't find it but I guess I was looking in the wrong places.